# Android Fragments Compatibility Issue

Tags: android, crash, android-fragments, compatibility

I have main activity of fragment

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Fragment fragment;
    Button btn1, btn2,btn3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        MyFragment myfragment = new MyFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.myFragment, myfragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        Fragment fragment = null;
        if(v == btn1){
            fragment = new Fragment1();
        }else if(v == btn2){
            fragment = new Fragment2();
        }

        FragmentTransaction transcation = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transcation.replace(R.id.myFragment,fragment);
        transcation.addToBackStack(null);
        transcation.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        transcation.commit();
    }
}
```

and three simple fragments similar like this

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    }
}
```

Its working fine with HC and ICS but if i try to run on older version 2.3. It crashes.... I have added supported library also but  does not work. and one more question... Kindly suggest me good tutorial or video which helps to move from normal development to fragments.

Comment: getFragmentManager() isn't supported in the compatibility package. Use getSupportFragmentManager() instead.

Comment: @Hang its not working :/

Comment: Try extending FragmentActivity instead of Activity

Comment: did already but not working

Comment: One last thing, do you have the correct package imported:android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: Now i have to update lots of classes with support and it getting better but one las thing Hang    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        MyFragment myfragment = new MyFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.myFragment, myfragment); 
        // It would not allow me to add
        ft.commit();